# Qt 5.1 Windows 7 - aboutToQuit() not called on windows logoff

Tags: windows, qt, qt5

If I exit my application normally, aboutToQuit is called and I can do some cleanup, however, if the user logs off of windows, my application closes immediately and aboutToQuit is never called.

The program functions as an application launcher that logs to a server.  Each time an application launches, it sends a message to a server with the name (you launch the application from within my app).

Normally, a user shuts down the application when they are done and I log the event.  If they shutdown the computer though, I want to send a application's shutdown log event in aboutToQuit, but that function is never called.

I've searched for options and short of making my application into a Windows service (haven't tried this yet), nothing is working.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is at least `QApplication::commitDataRequest()` or `QApplication::saveStateRequest()` signal emitted?

Comment: Nope, doesn't look like either of those are emitted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be fixed in Qt5.2.0 as I now receive a QApplication::commitDataRequest() signal at windows logoff.